# Inline responsive form elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a text input element and a submit input element that I need to be inline and responsive. The problem is that I can't find a way to get the text input element to be fluid without screwing up the positioning of the button. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the html structure I'm using.

```
<div class="search-call-to-action">
    <form action="#">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search charities by keyword or name...">
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve. The text input needs to be fluid.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4FbT.png

Comment: What do you mean by "responsive?"

Comment: You've posted your HTML, where is your CSS?

Comment: @ExplosionPills The text input needs to be fluid so it will shrink when the viewport size changes. The div surrounding this little form is inside of a bootstrap .container so the parent div is going to get smaller. Setting the width to a percentage doesn't seem to work because it will change the positioning of the button which cannot be fluid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have provided a jsfiddle with a working demo on how to achieve this. It uses the overflow property. Demo http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/vbdy9/

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Go" style="float: right" />
    <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
        <input type="text" name="term" style="width: 100%;" />
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to achieve this.  Then you should create queries for each resolution. Example:

```
@media (min-width: 320px){

div
{
    //some propererties in ems
}
```